# Java string replaceAll regex

Tags: java, regex, replace

Hi I want to remove certain words from a long string, there problem is that some words end with "s" and some start with a capital, basically I want to turn:

`"Hello cat Cats cats Dog dogs dog fox foxs Foxs"`

into:

`"Hello"`

at the moment I have this code but I want to improve on it, thanks in advance:

```
                    .replace("foxs", "")
                    .replace("Fox", "")
                    .replace("Dogs", "")
                    .replace("Cats", "")
                    .replace("dog", "")
                    .replace("cat", "")
```

Comment: Use case insensitive flag `(?i)` and `(?i)\s(?:fox|dog|cat)s?`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
String input = "Hello cat Cats cats Dog dogs dog fox foxs Foxs";
input = input.replaceAll("(?i)\\s*(?:fox|dog|cat)s?", "");
```

### Demo

Comment: I would remove one `\\s*`, otherwise `foo cat bar` would become `foobar` instead of (I am guessing preferred) `foo bar`.

Comment: @Pshemo Yes you're right ... the commenter S Jovan left a brilliant and flawless pattern about 30 seconds before I posted.

Comment: Yes, writing answer containing fully executable code takes more time than writing only solution :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can try to match everything except the word `Hello`.
Something like:

```
string.replaceAll("(?!Hello)\\b\\S+", "");
```

You can test it in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/XUwzM1/1).

The idea is to perform a negative lookahead for `Hello` word, and get any other word present.

Comment: One of `\\b` is redundant.

Comment: yes, you are right. I edit the answer and remove one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate patterns that match all combinations for a word. I.e. for `dog` you need the pattern `[Dd]ogs?`:

- `[Dd]` is a character class that matches both cases
- `s?` matches zero or one `s`
- the rest of the word will be case sensitive. I.e. `dOGS` will not be a match.

This is how you can put it together:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // it's easy to add any other word
    String original = "Hello cat Cats cats Dog dogs dog fox foxs Foxs";
    String[] words = {"fox", "dog", "cat"};
    String tmp = original;
    for (String word : words) {
        String firstChar = word.substring(0, 1);
        String firstCharClass = "[" + firstChar.toUpperCase() + firstChar.toLowerCase() + "]";
        String patternSrc = firstCharClass + word.substring(1) + "s?"; // [Ww]ords?
        tmp = tmp.replaceAll(patternSrc, "");
    }
    tmp = tmp.trim(); // to remove unnecessary spaces 
    System.out.println(tmp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you could pre-compile a list of the words you want and make it case insensitive something like:

```
    String str = "Hello cat Cats cats Dog dogs dog fox foxs Foxs";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("fox[s]?|dog[s]?|cat[s]?", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    String result = m.replaceAll("");
    System.out.println(result);
```

[s]? handles if there is a plural form, where the ? character will match 0 or 1

Comment: So you don't have to have it inside of there. it was more so in case you wanted to match a set of characters or range of characters at the end `[0-9]` or `[s|es]`. I agree this was not necessarily clear. So it could be just:
`Pattern.compile("foxs?|dogs?|cats?", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);`

Comment: It is good you realise that `s?` and `[s]?` will work same way (IMO adding `[` `]` makes it harder to understand - especially for someone new to regex - but that is matter of personal preference). Aside from that "or `[s|es]`" doesn't look like proper example (or you are misunderstanding it) since `[...]` can match only *single* character from set of characters defined in `[...]`. So `[s|es]` can match only `s` or `|` or `e` (putting `s` second time doesn't change anything here).

Comment: Valid points. In my second case it should have been (s|es) and I do agree that it does make it harder to understand, always room for improvement